# How to Retrieve SQL column from SharePoint list and update SQL data to SharePoint list?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sql-server

I have a table in SQL with some columns

I stored this SQL column in SharePoint list.

I want to retrieve this column from SharePoint list and store the SQL data value to `List1`.

Based on that  title in that same row the data should be updated.

Here i stored the SQL values in dt and stored the SQL columns in dtc.(from list).Now i want to compare dt and dtc and store the dt value in  list1.

Please some one help for this.

Comment: Is below solution works for you for some extent as i was confused a bit in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try below mentioned code if it helps you.

```
public override void Execute(Guid contentDbId)
        {

            try
            {
                // OpenSqlConnection();

                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site))
                {
                    using (SPWeb currWeb = site.OpenWeb())
                    {

                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                        SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                        SPList currList = currWeb.Lists.TryGetList("SqlAccess");
                        SPListItemCollection itemColl = currList.GetItems(query);

                        query.ViewFields = string.Concat(
                        "<FieldRef Name='Title'/>",
                        "<FieldRef Name='Server' />",
                        "<FieldRef Name='Database' />",
                        "<FieldRef Name='UserID' />",
                        "<FieldRef Name='Password' />");

                        SPListItemCollection oItemCol = currList.GetItems(query);

                        foreach (SPListItem oItem in oItemCol)
                        {
                            string cs = "Data Source='" + oItem["Server"]
                           + "';Initial Catalog='" + oItem["Database"]
                           + "';User ID='" + oItem["UserID"]
                           + "';Password='" + oItem["Password"] + "'";
                            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
                            cmd.Connection = con;



                            string SqlString = "SELECT * FROM ContractDetails WHERE ContractTitle = ContractTitle;";
                            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlString, con);

                            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                            con.Open();
                            sda.Fill(dt);
                            SPList list = currWeb.Lists.TryGetList("ContractDetails");

                            foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                            {
                                SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                                query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ContractTitle'/><Value Type='Text'>'" + dr["ContractTitle"].ToString() + "'</Value></Eq></Where>";
                                SPListItemCollection Listitems = list.GetItems(query);
                                if(Listitems.Count == 0)
                                {
                                    SPListItem item =list.Items.Add();
                                    item["ContractTitle"]=dr["ContractTitle"].ToString();
                                    item["ContractID"]=dr["ContractID"].ToString();
                                    item["ContractArea"] = dr["ContractArea"].ToString();
                                    item["ModifiedDate"] = DateTime.Now;
                                    item.Update();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    foreach (SPListItem item in Listitems)
                                    {
                                        item["ContractID"] = dr["ContractID"].ToString();
                                        item.Update();
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                           con.Close();

                        }
                    }
                }
```

**Please change column names as per your list column names**